# Removing the "dear xxx" part of ros answers?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way to make the askbot stop using the header starting with "Dear xxx, somebody has answered...".

This is useless information: I know my name and the question being tackled is already in the email title. This also prevent getting useful information in the gmail email preview.

Additionally, I personally find the header extremely irritating, like a middle-man telling me that somebody has said something, when I can hear the something.

The bottom line, is that I would want ros answers to behave as nicely and unobtrusively as the ros-users mailing list.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9308/removing-the-%22dear-xxx%22-part-of-ros-answers?/) by [Cedric](https://answers.ros.org/users/66/cedric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2011-03-10**:
The link to unsubscribe must be there - by law :)! but the wording could be better.

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2011-03-06**:
"Please note - you can easily change how often you receive these notifications or unsubscribe. Thank you for your interest in our forum!" is also pretty annoying. You might want to open a ticket on the ROS Trac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please suggest something better, will be glad to make a reasonable change in askbot. Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) with karma: 26 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2011-03-10**:
I believe the suggestion is to simply remove this header and footer completely.